Does the shell's & operator perform redirects before or after starting asynchronous commands?
Consider the following script:
rm -f /tmp/bar
echo foo >/tmp/bar &
tail -f < /tmp/bar

When processing the echo line, does the shell first perform the redirect opening /tmp/bar for writing and then launch the asynchronous command? Or does the redirect happen inside the asynchronous process?
If the former, then this fragment is race free as the tail line happens strictly after /tmp/foo is created. If the latter, there is a chance that the open for the echo happens after tail -f < /tmp/bar and that fails if so as /tmp/bar is non-existent then.
I tried with different shells, but I was not able to detect a race. But that is inconclusive as the chance of the race is small.

Hmm, I tried: for sh in bash dash ksh zsh; do rm -f bar; if ! $sh -c 'true > bar & [ -e bar ]' ; then echo $sh: bar not created yet; fi; done , and every time the output was: bash: bar not created yet dash: bar not created yet ksh: bar not created yet. Only zsh seems to have created the file in time. Versions: bash 5.2.032-1 dash 0.5.12-1 ksh 2020.0.0-3 zsh 5.9-5 on Arch Linux

Hmm, interesting.It definitely seems to hit-or-miss with zsh. Sometimes I get zsh: bar not created yet, most times I don't. Extending that loop to include ash, where ash is ash() { busybox sh "$@"; }, bash, dash, busybox sh and ksh all consistently output bar not created yet.

So the conclusion is that the redirect happens after the asynchronous process start. That sucks as it implies to fix the race I will need to use something like:
rm -f /tmp/bar
exec 3>/tmp/bar
echo foo >&3 &
exec exec 3>&-
tail -f < /tmp/bar

This is indeterminate. What happens is more likely to be determined by the kernel & will involve tick rate, timer support, preemption model, memory pressure and a whole lot more.

Even simpler you could use tail -f --retry /tmp/bar and resolve the race condition, however I would've hoped the behavior was deterministic here, too.

I wonder if something like { foo & } > bar would work

@ikkachu your suggestions is a good workaround for the given code, but in the real code I need to redirect stdin and & closes stdin

@IgorBukanov only if it’s not redirected — { foo & } < baz > bar works.

@StephenKitt That does not work at least with dash. According to its manpage: "If the shell is not interactive, the standard input of an  asynchronous command is set to /dev/null." This is also what I observed.

@IgorBukanov ah that’s a shame, it works in bash and zsh but I didn’t try with dash.
